# Absolute url in anchor tag does not change address in the address bar

Tags: html, dns, subdomain, anchor

I have a subdomain like blog.domain.com. I have kept an anchor tag here

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com">Visit</a>
```

(i.e. when someone clicks this link he should get redirected to the original domain.com)

When i click on this link it redirects me to the site at domain.com but the address in the address bar remains the same (i.e. blog.subdomain.com). Am i doing something wrong here? This is a simple static html page and the anchor tag is not referenced(and/or manipulated) anywhere else. I guess the main problem may be somewhere in the dns provider. I have added a *forwarding with masking* rule in my dns settings. i.e. when a request for blog.domain.com comes it is forwarded to www.domain.com/blog without changing the actual url in the address bar. Could this be a possible cause. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is that you're in an iframe. If that's the case, try this:

`<a href="http://www.domain.com" target="_parent">Visit</a>`

Comment: I just edited my question. i am not using an iframe but still your solution worked. Can you please explain what was wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Here's some good documentation on the behavior: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Not sure why it's necessary in your case if you're not using an iframe, there must be something else going on.